# Is this an appropiate case to use union vs reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, unions

I am receiving four words(32bits) of data from an io device. The first word in the message tells me what the data is that is coming in. I was wondering if this is a case for using union or reinterpret_cast.

Here is my use case...

```cpp
struct Plain {
  uint32_t  type;
  uint32_t data1;
  uint32_t data2;
  uint32_t data3;
}
struct Special1 {
  uint32_t  type;
  uint32_t data1;
  float    data2;
  uint32_t data3;
}

struct Special2 {
  uint32_t  type;
  uint32_t data1;
  float    data2;
  uint16_t data3;
  uint16_t data4;
}
union My_union {
  Plain    p1;
  Special1 p2;
  Special2 p3;

}
void foo(const Special1& x);
void foo(const Special2& x);
int main() {
  My_union x;
  read(&x.p1, sizeof(Plain)); // read from an IO device
  if(x.p1.type == 1)
  {
    foo(x.p2);
  }
  else
  {
    foo(x.p3);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to figure out if this is an appropriate case to use a union, or is a cast still the way to go and if so why?

Comment: Neither is correct, `std::memcpy` is the only correct choice

Comment: Both violate the [strict aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: @UnholySheep this does answer the question I asked. The only reason I didn't want to do this is because the copies become costly in a time sensitive system since my actual structs are much larger.

Comment: Any decent optimizing compiler will optimize out the copy into something that is functionally equivalent to reinterpreting.

Comment: @CruzJean the union version does not violate strict aliasing; it violates the rule about accessing objects that don't exist

Comment: `uint16_t data3; uint16_t data4;` there might be padding between these members on 32-bit systems. If you use gcc, go with compiler extensions, add `__attribute__((__packed__))`. Also, if the first member is the type, why not `struct msg { uint32_t type; union { Plain plain; Special1 p1; Special2 p2; }; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object `x` would be properly initialized, the `if` statements in `main()`  would be legal, because despite the following restriction in clause `[class.union]/1` of the C++ standard:

> ***1)*** In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not
>   ended. **At most one** of the non-static data members of an object
>   of union type **can be active at any time**, that is, the value of at most
>   one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any
>   time.

the following exception allows you to access the common member `type`:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions:
>   If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs
>   that **share a common initial sequence**, and if a non-static data
>   member of an object of this standard-layout union type is active and
>   is one of the standard-layout structs, **it is permitted to inspect the
>   common initial sequence of any** of the standard-layout struct members.

But the problem in your snippet, is that you create a union object `x` without activating any of its members (`[basic.life]`/1.2):

> (...) if the object is a union member or subobject thereof, its
>   lifetime only begins if that union member is the initialized member in
>   the union

This means that you read some data directly into the union object when no member is active, so that still no member is active. Following strictly the standard, I'd understand that this is not guaranteed to work at all.

The right way to do it, would be to read the `type`,  then intialize the relevant member to and read therein the rest of the struct (or read everything into a buffer and copy following a similar strategy). However, in practice,  your code will work on most compilers.